# Unindexed properties with bulk loader

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm using python bulk loader to load a csv file to appengine and I see that all properties are automatically indexed.

How can I leave some properties unindexed?

PD: I'm using the new configuration:

> appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=xxx.csv --kind=MyEntity --url=http://xxx.appspot.com/remote_api

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this: http://alex.cloudware.it/2012/08/unindexed-entity-properties-with-bulk.html